# Eloquent filter relationship records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get only those records from relationship where certain column is not null. Here are the tables:

###### Items:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 |
| 2 | item2 |

###### Parts:

| id | item_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | part1 |
| 2 | 1 | part2 |
| 3 | 2 | null |
| 4 | 2 | part3 |

Relation inside `Item` model:

```
public function parts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Part');
}
```

Relation inside `Part` model:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Item');
}
```

I have tried with this code:

```
Item::with('parts')
    ->whereHas('parts', function($query) {
       $query->whereNotNull('name');
    })
    ->get();
```

And it retrieves only `item` with `id = 1`. I would like to get `item` with `id = 2` also, but only with `part` where `name` is not `null`.

Comment: It should be working as expected... instead of doing `->get()` do `->toSql()` and share the resulting query please.

Comment: I guess you have to use filter() method in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter

Comment: @matiaslauriti In the accepted answer it is well explained. But look at my comment bellow to check something related to what you asked me to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that item2 as 2 parts

PARTS:

| id | item_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | null |
| 4 | 2 | part3 |

Your query returns parts (id: 3 and 4) because you're querying:

> Get me all the items with the parts, where items have part with a name.

But you need

> Get me all the items with the parts that have a name, where the items have part with a name.

To do this, you need to add a subquery

```php
Item::with(['parts' => function($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('name');
}])
    ->whereHas('parts', function($query) {
        return $query->whereNotNull('name');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you, and thank you even more for the explanation. I have never used query conditions inside `with` part since I didn't know what it would be used for. Now I know

Comment: Here's something that confused me a bit at the beginning.
Yours and mine queries return absolutely the same SQL once I run `->toSql()` and it looks like `select * from "items" where exists (select * from "parts" where "items"."id" = "parts"."item_id" and "name" is not null)`.
But probably behind the scene something is done once the records are returned, due the condition inside `with` part

Comment: Because when you use `with`, it perform two queries. The first one is to get the item as you already have. And the second one is `select * from parts where parts.item_id in (1, 2) and name is not null`  You can dump the query inside the anonymous function `dump($query->toSql());` and see the same result. But I would much recommend [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to see all queries executed.

Comment: Thanks for further explanation. I am using [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope).
Guess it's similar to debugbar

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much similar and serve the same purpose. You should be able to see that query in telescope queries history.